# Does any SSL certificate authority handle third-level .name domains?

Tags: domains, https, security-certificate, name

I am the owner of a third-level `.name` domain of form `subdomain.example.name`. The `.name` domain hierarchy is somewhat unusual in that generally one registers a third-level domain such as mine, rather than a second-level domain ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name) explains this in more detail). Thus no one actually owns `example.name` nor is it available for registration, and I have full control over `subdomain.example.name`.

I recently got a free StartSSL certificate, but was disappointed to find out that the domain name validation process does not handle third-level domains. I'm willing to pay for a certificate from another authority if I must, but I'd hate to do so only to find after the fact that I can't use it with my domain.

Will any certificate authority validate third-level `.name` domains like mine? (I'm not interested in discussing the overall relative merits of one authority over another, only whether any of them satisfy this specific criterion.)

Comment: It seems my question is on hold as "asking to recommend a tool, library or favorite offsite resource." But in fact I'm not asking for a preferred or favorite one, or a recommendation: I'm asking for *any* resource satisfying the description of "certificate authority that validates third-level .name domains." This seems sufficiently controversy-free since it isn't a matter of opinion as to whether a certificate authority does or does not provide this service.

Comment: **2018 answer:** Let's Encrypt seems to validate everything I've thrown at it, including subdomains that I don't even own but that are pointed to my servers. I'm sure it would validate `.name` domains all the same.

Comment: There is absolutely no technical reason why a CA could not verify those names and hence deliver certificates, no matter how many labels they have (a .US domain name can have 4 or 5 subdomains in it). Except in the presence of some CAA DNS records in some parent zones that would prohibit certificates in child zones.